# A Java interface to enforce by design the output type of unknown methods of its implementors?

Tags: java, generics, types, interface, architecture

At present, I've defined an *empty* interface X that is implemented by some other interfaces (just to identify them elsewhere).

All interfaces that implement X may provide as many public methods as they wish, but I want to enforce by design/by architecture, that all of them (note again that they are unknown to X) will return a type that is derived from the same abstract class Y.

Ist their any way I can do this in Java?

In the following example, X should enforce that only types derived from Y are returned by U and V.

```
public interface X {
    // I'm empty at present.
}

public interface U extends X {
    public A getA();
    public B getB(String bIn);
}

public interface V extends X {
    public C getC(Integer cIn);
    public D getD(); // Compile should fail!
}

public class A extends Y {
}

public class B extends Y {
}

public class C extends Y {
}

public class D {
    // D does *not* extend Y.
}
```

Comment: Only option i can think of is to declare all methods in `X` like `public Y getA(); public Y getD();`. Then the method `getD()` cannot return type `D` in `V`.

Comment: There is reflection, of course; but this looks like a XY problem. What is the need behind this?

Comment: The "need" behind this is to enforce by design that short-term external programmers don't disobey the architectural specifications of our system when they need to add a new interface V and its implementation, and to prevent accidental as well as conscious abuse in order to quickly provide "creative solutions". To use reflection may be overkill though; and to have any method return D is out of the question, sorry. Maybe there's another alternative approach to the matter? Some design pattern that escaped us?

Comment: Maybe I should add that in the above example, the interfaces U and V provide the external interface of the system, and that new interfaces like U and V are being added regularly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to enforce this with the java type system.  You would therefore be left with:

- reflection
- customised static analysis
- code reviews & developer education

I would stay away from reflection and static analysis.  You haven't said what problem you are trying to solve with this, so it's difficult to give any alternate approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @fge that this sounds like an XY problem, but I think you might be able to get something to work at compile-time.

You want to place a requirement on every method of a type, but Java only lets you specify that there exist some methods satisfying some requirements on a type, so you will have to refactor `U` and `V`.

In the set-up, I've made `X` specify that any implementors must provide a way to return a `Y` descendent. I've also specified that `Y` is an abstract class.

```
interface X {
    Y getY();
}

abstract class Y {

}
```

Then, I looked at your interfaces `U` and `V`, and their methods `U#getA()`, `U#getB(String)`, `V#getC(Integer)`, `V#getD()`. All of these methods can be put in their own class.

```
class UA implements X {
    public A getY() {
        ...
    }
}

class UB implements X {
    private final String s;

    public UB(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public B getY() {
        ...
    }
}

class VC implements X {
    private final Integer integer;

    public VC(Integer integer) {
        this.integer = integer;
    }

    public C getY() {
        ...
    }
}

// COMPILE-TIME ERROR
class VD implements X {
    public D getY() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, anything that implements X must provide Y. The problem now is that `UA`, `UB`, `VC`, and `VD` can offer other methods. You've said you only want them to provide methods that return `Y`. To get around this, you can replace X with a `final` concrete class, which only provides a single constructor that you control.

Replace `X` with `YFactory` (everywhere in the code)

```
interface YFactory {
    Y getY();
}
```

Now, specify X as a concrete class which only has one constructor:

```
final class X {
    private final YFactory yFactory;

    public X(YFactory yFactory) {
        this.yFactory = yFactory;
    }

    public Y getY() {
        return yFactory.getY();
    }
}
```

All together:

```
final class X {
    private final YFactory yFactory;

    public X(YFactory yFactory) {
        this.yFactory = yFactory;
    }

    public Y getY() {
        return yFactory.getY();
    }
}

abstract class Y {

}

interface YFactory {
    Y getY();
}

class A extends Y {

}

class B extends Y {
}

class C extends Y {
}

class D {
    // D does *not* extend Y.
}

class UA implements YFactory {
    public A getY() {
        return null;
    }
}

class UB implements YFactory {
    private final String s;

    public UB(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public B getY() {
        return null;
    }
}

class VC implements YFactory {
    private final Integer integer;

    public VC(Integer integer) {
        this.integer = integer;
    }

    public C getY() {
        return null;
    }
}

class VD implements YFactory {
    public D getY() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you know that any `X` only has methods that return `Y`.